# Ugly spacing in lstinline

Tags: spacing, listings, highlighting

I am using the `listings` package to typeset Erlang source code in my thesis. For short snippets, I use `\lstinline`. The result is often unsatisfying. Consider the following example, which contains `\lstinline` twice:

I am using `lstlistings` to typeset `Erlang` source code in my thesis. For short

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb} % needed for listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=erlang}

\usepackage{pslatex}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
est laborum \lstinline|config:read(rt_frt_reduction_ratio_strategy)|.
sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, \lstinline{ugly:typeset/1} sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

The result contains spaces where they should not occur (or at least less wide):

[image: result of the example code above]

Is there a way to tell `listings` to avoid such spacing?

Comment: Use `columns=fullflexible`.

Comment: Using `columns=fullflexible` did the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the option `columns=fullflexible`.

Comment: Excellent! I wonder why this behavior is not the default.